# How to put the <p>...</p> tag very first para in the environment like theorem

Tags: tex4ht, para

I am trying to create a one environment in tex4ht, in the html file `<p>... </p>` tag is missing in the very first para of the environment

I am using the below tex coding

```
\documentclass{book}
\newenvironment{exe}{Exercise: }{}
\begin{document}
This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing.

\begin{exe}
This Theorem explain how it works in the example

This Theorem explain how it works in the example
\end{exe}
This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional text).

\end{document}
```

and I used the below coding in the cfg file

```
\ConfigureEnv{exe}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="Theorem">}}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
   {}
   {}
```

The output in the html file is:

```
<p class="noindent" >This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order</p>
<div class="Theorem">Exercise:  This Theorem explain how it works in the example
<p class="indent" >This Theorem explain how it works in the example</p>
</div>
<p class="indent" >This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle 
Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional
text).</p>
```

I compile the file with the following arguments

```
htlatex sample "sample.cfg,xhtml"
```

Please suggest how to insert the para tag `<p>...</p>` in the opening para of the new environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert explicit paragraphs with `\par` command in this case:

```
\ConfigureEnv{exe}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="Theorem">}\par}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}
   {}
   {}
```

The result:

```html
  <div class="Theorem">
<p class="indent">   Exercise:  This Theorem explain how it works in the example
</p><p class="indent">   This Theorem explain how it works in the example
</p></div>
<p class="indent">   This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle
Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional
text).
</p>
```

Comment: Its working now thank you for your timely help. I think Inserting paragraph tag is more tricky in TeX4HT

Comment: sorry another one doubt, why the closing para tag `</p>` coming with newline in the html file, how to run on the tag with the line.

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran the newlines are inserted everywhere, where the line in broken in the `DVI` file, so every paragraph inserts new line.

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran but you can use something like `HTML tidy` to reformat the HTML file.

Comment: I want to generate xml structures from TeX4ht!!!

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran tidy can support xml as well

Comment: I will check, and i will try to use for clean up in the html file.